# What permission do I need to read zip files - android 11?

Tags: android-permissions, zip, user-permissions, android-file, android-11

I'm working on zip files (android-studio-java)

and I tried below solutions:

1. android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE   ---> failed (no read access for zip file)
2. [Access documents and other files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)      ---> failed (no read access for zip file)
3. [android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) ---> passed

My question is: Is there any lower level of permission for zip files or I have to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**, no need for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     // you can set here the type you need setType(application/zip)
     intent.setType("*/*");
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     startActivityForResult(intent, ZIP_READ_CODE);
```

OnActivityResult

```
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          case ZIP_READ_CODE: {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                File file = null;
                try {
                    file = read_uri_to_file(uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //handle error
                }
          }
     }
```

Read the File:

```
    private File read_uri_to_file(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    String displayName = "";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        try {
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    //create temp file to copy and handle selected file
    File file =  File.createTempFile(
            FilenameUtils.getBaseName(displayName),
            "."+FilenameUtils.getExtension(displayName)
    );

    //copy selected file, to a temp file
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file);
    return file;
}
```